# How to create dynamically changing color text in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, colors

I want to use an image which contains black and white parts as a background and I wonder if it is possible to creat text that will change depending on which color is under it(consider that it’s scrolling view, so the color under exact letter can change)

I mean when the background under the letter is white the colour of the letter would become black and then you scroll down for example and now the background under the same letter is black so the letter become white

I am new to Swift, so would really appreciate explanation❤️

Comment: Look into blend modes.

Comment: To clarify, I assume you mean the colors would change in specific, programmatic way, not simply be transparent (and have the appearance shift as the background scrolls, (aka, the secondary text labels in FaceTime.app).

Comment: I mean when the background under the letter is white the colour of the letter would become black and then you scroll down for example and now the background under the same letter is black so the letter become white